# How To Combine 2 MySQL Tables Like This? (Many-To-One Relationship)

Tags: mysql

I have UserComments table like this :

```
1 | Frank | hello world
2 | Jane | Hi there
3 | Frank | this is my comments
4 | Frank | I think I need some sleep
5 | Jason | I need to buy new MacBook
6 | Jane | Please invite my new Blackberry PIN
```

On the other hand, I have FriendList table contains :

```
1 | Jason
2 | Jane
```

Let's say my friends ID always BETWEEN 1 AND 5.

And since Frank is not my friend, I'm not able to see his comments. how to have combined tables like this (ORDER BY UserComments.ID DESC) :

```
1 | Jane | Please invite my new Blackberry PIN
2 | Jason | I need to buy new MacBook
3 | Jane | Hi there
```

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    SELECT A.ID, B.UserName, B.Comment 
      FROM FriendList A
INNER JOIN UserComments B ON A.ID = B.ID
  ORDER BY A.ID DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this::

```
Select 
* 
from 
user_comments inner join friend_List on (join criteria)
where user_Id = ? order by user_comments.id desc
```